# Best approach to correlate discrete and continuous variables using machine-learning technique

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, discrete-data, continuous-data

I am using a scale which consists of discrete values: 0 (normal), 1 (mild), 2 (moderate), 3 (severe) and these values are for 4 components.  I have measured 200 patients on this scale. Each patient has four discrete numbers. I am going to find the correlations between this scale and some continuous variables; these continuous variables are also measured for 200 patients.

Goal: To generate these discrete values with a machine-learning algorithm based on the continuous variables.

1. What is best method for feature selection (for the continuous variables), Spearman correlation?

   If the continuous variables were highly correlated with discrete values; does it mean I should consider them as features?
2. Which classification method would be the best?
3. Do you suggest I use Weka?

Comment: This is a variant on [Correlation between discrete and continuous variables](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62741/correlation-between-discrete-and-continuous-variables). It is much better (a) to pay attention to comments already given (if appropriate, explain why they are wrong, irrelevant or otherwise not what you want) (b) not to spawn multiple versions of the same question.

Comment: Why are you asking a new question here, @user27379? Is there something new about this question? If so, can you edit this Q to make it more distinct from your previous Q? Are you not satisfied w/ the answer to the previous Q? If so, it would be best to edit / update that Q w/ what you didn't understand / still want to know.